C# - Semantic Kernel - Using Planners correctly
I'm trying to understand Semantic Kernel by coding my own E-Mail Agent.
I provided 3 native functions (EmailPlugin.cs):

Fetch E-Mails
Order them by Date descending
Get first 'x' mails from a list

So when i ask the Kernel to Give me the latest 3 E-Mails i expect a plan like:

-Step 1 -> Step 2 -> Step 3

But the plan it automatically chooses is:

Step 1 -> Step 3

How can i tell him what the plan should look like in that specific case?
I think i missunderstood something here... I created a EmailsPlanner so the Kernel can get info about the necessary steps for that specific Task (latest 3 E-Mails) but the Method in EmailsPlanner is not even hit.
From the documentation just can't figure out the necessary steps i need to do to tell the planner the correct plan to achieve that goal...
Here is my code:
Program.cs
// add appsettings.json
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

// Create the kernel
var kernelBuilder = Kernel.CreateBuilder();

kernelBuilder.Services.AddOpenAIChatCompletion(
    config["OPEN_AI_MODEL_ID"],
    config["OPEN_AI_API_KEY"]
    );

kernelBuilder.Plugins.AddFromType<EmailPlugin>();
kernelBuilder.Plugins.AddFromType<EmailsPlanner>();
kernelBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

var kernel =  kernelBuilder.Build();

var planner = new HandlebarsPlanner(new HandlebarsPlannerOptions() { AllowLoops = true });

// Start the conversation
while (true)
{
    // Get user input
    Console.Write("User > ");
    var goal = Console.ReadLine();

    // Enable auto function calling
    OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings openAIPromptExecutionSettings = new()
    {
        ToolCallBehavior = ToolCallBehavior.AutoInvokeKernelFunctions
    };

    var plan = await planner.CreatePlanAsync(kernel, goal);

    Console.WriteLine($"Plan > {plan}");

    var result = await plan.InvokeAsync(kernel, new KernelArguments(openAIPromptExecutionSettings));

    Console.Write($"Assistant > {result}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

EmailPlugin.cs
[KernelFunction]
[Description("Gets a list of all E-Mails")]
public async Task<List<EmailMessage>> GetEmailsAsync()
{
    // Fetch emails (cached and new)
    var messages = await FetchEmailsFromServerAsync();

    // Save updated list to cache
    var updatedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(messages);
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(_cacheFilePath, updatedJson);

    return messages;
}

[KernelFunction]
[Description("Sort E-Mails by date descending")]
public async Task<List<EmailMessage>> SortEmailsDescendingAsync(
    [Description("The list of E-Mails that should be sorted")] List<EmailMessage> emails
)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var sortedEmails = emails.OrderBy(email =>
        {
            DateTime.TryParseExact(email.Date, "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var date);
            return date;
        }).ToList();

        return sortedEmails;
    });
}

[KernelFunction]
[Description("Gets the first 'x' E-Mails of the given list, where 'x' is a specified amount")]
public Task<List<EmailMessage>> GetFirstEmails(
    [Description("The list of E-Mails")] List<EmailMessage> emails,
    [Description("amount of E-Mail that should be fetched from the list")] int amount
)
{
    return Task.FromResult(emails.Take(amount).ToList());
}

EmailsPlanner.cs
[KernelFunction]
[Description("Returns back the required steps to get the latest 'x' E-Mails, where 'x' is a fix input")]
[return: Description("The required steps to get the latest 'x' E-Mails")]
public Task<string> RequiredStepsForFetchingMailsAsync(
    [Description("An Integer value representing how many mails should be fetched")] int amount
)
{
    var result = $"""
    I want to get the latest {amount} E-Mails. Here are the necessary steps to achieve the goal:
    1. Get the E-Mails
    2. Order them descending by date
    3. Get the first {amount} E-Mails from the ordered list.
    """;

    // Return the plan back to the agent
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}


Which model are you using? This is prompt engineering problem to solve, and the best way to construct the prompt will depend on whether you're using gpt-3.5-turbo, gpt-4, gpt-4-turbo, etc. Also, Do you know if the EmailsPlanner function is being called? You might be able to make this work simple by including that prompt in the ask for the planner rather than as a separate function that may or may not be called.

Im using gpt-3.5-turbo... Yes the EmailsPlanner function is NOT called. I was hoping i can keep it as simple as possible so that I dont have to send a 5000 Token promt every time i want a simple request like getting recent mails...

It will end up taking fewer total tokens without that function call. The prompt in that function will end up as part of a request-response anyway. With gpt-3.5-turbo, a prompt should include a step-by-step description of the ask. If you want it to go through the function, then your ask can be something like, "First, check 'RequiredStepsForFetchingMails' for required instructions, then use available tools to accomplish {goal}"

I'd love to have it a little more generic. As my goal is to have my own GPT that can handle several Task about my Mails but can also for example anwer questions about Files on my Fileserver.
It should be possible though to give the planner more knowledge for special cases. e.g tell him if he wants to achieve goal XYZ he has to call Plugin1.Function1, then Plugin2.Function1, Plugin1.Function3 and so on...

Here's what it boils down to - if you want complex tasks done from relatively simple prompts, you're not going to make that happen consistently with gpt-3.5-turbo. I ran a version of your code 5 times with gpt-4-turbo and it got it right every time. gpt-3.5-turbo consistently misses the Sort Emails step (when it was able to generate a valid handlebars plan at all).
You have 2 options: 1. Settle for longer, more specific prompts for each task, or 2. Use gpt-4-turbo.

You don't necessarily need a plan to make this work, you can add your plugins like you do already and just provide a prompt.
With that the LLM will make the proper function calling interactions automatically.
Ensure you use the latest OpenAI models that support function calling (after NOV-2023)

OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings openAIPromptExecutionSettings = new()
{
    ToolCallBehavior = ToolCallBehavior.AutoInvokeKernelFunctions
};

var kernelBuilder = Kernel.CreateBuilder();

kernelBuilder.Services.AddOpenAIChatCompletion(
    config["OPEN_AI_MODEL_ID"],
    config["OPEN_AI_API_KEY"]
    );

kernelBuilder.Plugins.AddFromType<EmailPlugin>();
kernelBuilder.Plugins.AddFromType<EmailsPlanner>();
kernelBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

var kernel =  kernelBuilder.Build();

var result = kernel.InvokePromptAsync($"""
    I want to get the latest {{$amount}} E-Mails. Here are the necessary steps to achieve the goal:
    1. Get the E-Mails
    2. Order them descending by date
    3. Get the first {{$amount}} E-Mails from the ordered list.
""", new(openAIPromptExecutionSettings) { ["amount"] = amount });

Console.WriteLine(result);

